# Best way to execute a POST query in PHP with long or complicated forms?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a few forms with content that the users can edit, a simple example is profile.php with five fields of which the user can change three (for now); name, surname and address. The html form pulls their existing data from sql and presents it in editable text boxes.

Below is how I get the various variables:

```
<?php
//PHP to submit content of profile fields.

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
//Set ID for insert statement
$id=$rows['id'];
//Get name from form
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
$name = $rows['name'];
}
elseif($_POST['name'] == $rows['name']){
    $name = $rows['name'];
}
else{
        $name = $_POST['name'];
            print $name;
}
//Get Surname from form
if(empty($_POST['surname'])){
$name = $rows['surname'];
}
elseif($_POST['surname'] == $rows['surname']){
    $surname = $rows['surname'];
}
else{
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
}
//Get Address from form
if(empty($_POST['address'])){
$name = $rows['address'];
}
elseif($_POST['address'] == $rows['address']){
    $address = $rows['address'];
}
else{
        $address = $_POST['address'];
}


$sql    = "UPDATE usr SET name = ?, surname = ?, address = ?  
where id = ?"
```

(and then the rest of the code to submit the query follows, I am not going to include that here unless you guys need it. It's basic mysqli stuff.)

The above just feels very wonky and long winded, is there a better way of doing this, especially if the forms get longer? As it is I made my "if(empty)" as simple as possible to avoid having to craft an error echo for each one since the function basically keeps whatever is in the form when loaded if the user tries to enter an empty field.

I feel that once I start adding birth date, telephone number and other things the queries are going to get very long, the sql update statement is going to be crazy with "ssssss" etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the code is all the same for each field, you could probably write a function to handle it. Is it intentional, for example, that you always assign the database result (presumably that's what `$rows` is) to `$name` if your form variable is empty?

Comment: Yes it is intentional, I haven't found a better way to make sure the value that WAS in the field doesn't get inadvertently deleted by the user and submitted as blank, without checking for input errors after submit and returning the user to the page to fix the error. Could you clarify on the function for handling multiple input post statements?

Comment: But what I meant was, surely for the `surname` form field, you'd assign that to `$surname`, and for the address you'd assign it to `$address`, as you do if there _is_ something in the form field?

Comment: As for the function, I'd pass in the form field and the database field that it would default to if the form field was empty, and return whichever is appropriate. So you'd call it as something like `$name = field_validate($_POST['name'], $rows['name'])` and your function code would decide what to return.

Comment: This post may be better suited to [**Code Review Stack Exchange**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you Martin. I was not aware of that one. Will keep in mind for the future. Appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an array with you keys and then iterate through them and extract from Post your value and build another array with valid data.

```
$keys = ['name', 'surname', 'address'];
$final = [];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $final[$key] = $_POST[$key] ?? $rows[$key];
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. This is exactly what I was looking for, especially when combined with some other suggestions from the other commenters. Replacing my previously chosen answer with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary function, too:

```
$name = (empty($_POST['name'])? $rows['name'] : $_POST['name']);
```

for example. If the call to `empty()` is true (the form variable is empty) it will return the variable from `$rows`, and if not it will return the variable from the form.

Your extra bit of code to see if the form field is the same as the database field is a bit of a waste, because if it is, there's no difference between using the form field and using the database field.

Comment: This is a lot neater than I did it, and barring a way to include all the variables in one statement this may be the best option for now. Marking as answer.

Comment: As long as your variable names are the same as your form field names and database column names, you could probably `foreach()` through the `$_POST` array and use a dynamic variable name. Something like `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $$key = (empty($_POST[$key]) ? $rows[$key] : $value)); }` but I'm not 100% certain it would make it easier to read, if it even works.